# convert string data into Type for List<>

Tags: c#-4.0

I'd like to take a string and create a typed List based on the
"Type" documented in the string. For example, suppose str is "System.string". I'd
like the method to create a List for me. Of course, the string could contain text
that "references" any object in the assembly. I've unsuccessfully tried the following:

```
    Type classType = Type.GetType(str);
    List<classType> wgList = new List<classType>();
```

I get a message stating that "classType is a field but is used like a type"..

## How do I fix this up to get what I need ?

The following code provided a nice solution:

```
 Type ty = Type.GetType(ItemType); 
 wgList = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(ty));
```

Comment: I used the following to provide what I needed:

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that or i don't understand what is your purpose?

Use List< object > instead.

You may use Extension method is Cast< T>() in System.Linq namespace to convert your List< object > to List< T >.

```
List<Entry> entries = wgList.Cast<Entry>().ToList()
```

Comment: I am trying to create a strongly typed list based on the string contents.